# Cannot find articles/new.html.erb in my Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a blog application that I have created in Rails. I followed [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial.

So, I cannot find `new.html.erb` in my app/views/articles. I specifically created this file. The file, `new.html.erb`, located in app/views/articles holds the form that is required to create new article posts. I did a search through all of my Rails files and it is nowhere to be found. But the funny thing is, my Rails application is still fully functional. I can still create new article posts without any trouble. The reason I want the file is so I can add a Trix Rich Text Editor to the form. I noticed this problem after I installed one of the following gems:

`gem 'rails_admin', github: 'sferik/rails_admin'`

`gem 'rails_admin_rollincode', '~> 1.0'`

The path to create a new article post when running the server is localhost:3000/admin/articles/new.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `rails_admin`. This gem builds forms on the fly for your models.

Find the relevant code in at [/views/rails_admin/main/new.html.haml](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/new.html.haml) in the gem:

```
 = rails_admin_form_for @object, url: new_path(model_name: @abstract_model.to_param), as: @abstract_model.param_key, html: { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal denser", data: { title: @page_name } } do |form|
  = form.generate action: :create
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That clears up a lot of confusion. But how would I go about editing that form in order to add Trix capability, a Rich Text Editor.